# Redraw all layers in a different projection in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a few kinds of tilelayers and they are in different projections. Some are in EPSG3857, and the others are in EPSG3395. On changing a tilelayer I set map.options.crs = layer.crs. So the map is in different projection now. But the map has a lot of polygons and markers and they're still in the old projection. So I need to redraw them in the new projection. Is there a way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```
map._resetView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom(), true); //rerender layers
```